# tortoise svn shows useid, how can I change displayed name for author

Tags: svn, userid, author

Our org uses funny user ids - rzhxxn etc.

In tortoise svn log/blame etc, i want to see the author name.

Is there anyway to create a mapping file to see the real name instead of id?

Answer (score 1):

No, Subversion takes your user account (i.e. authenticated account's) name as `svn:author` property. There is no way for you, as a regular user (i.e. non-admin) to change it.