# tortoise svn change default author name

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

No answers to [a previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275056/tortoise-svn-shows-useid-how-can-i-change-displayed-name-for-authorhttp://) 2 years ago. 
I'm using tortoisesvn on windows.

The default author commit name is not what I want.

Is there a way to set this explicitly or map it to something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tortoise svn shows useid, how can I change displayed name for author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275056/tortoise-svn-shows-useid-how-can-i-change-displayed-name-for-author)

Comment: Please don't open a question that's an exact duplicate of one you've already found just because you didn't like the answer (or lack thereof).